# Jetpack Compose Pager Views/Screens Caching

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewpager, pager

I have a HorizontalPager implementation which loads composable screens as different positions are scrolled through. I would like to have the pager load the screens only once, and have them cached so that no re-compositions or redrawing is happening again on subsequent loads/visits. I've already fiddled with the `beyondBoundsPageCount` parameter but it's not achieving the behavior I would like for some reason. (i.e: re-compositions are happening again on every screen visit)

Comment: Please add the code that you currently have, both for the Pager and the Items that are displayed in the Pager. Are you using a LaunchedEffect? And may I also ask, why do you want to avoid a recomposition? If you properly persist state in a ViewModel, a recomposition is not a problem.